# CocoaFob - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is a weird error!  I'm getting:

```
ld: framework not found CocoaFob
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked all my build settings - and they appear correct.  CocoaFob.framework is in my Linked Frameworks and Libraries - showing healthy and black.  For some reason though, the damned framework isn't found when I try to link.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Once possible clue is that when I try to the cocoafob application ( from here: https://github.com/glebd/cocoafob ) I get exactly the same error. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Is it in Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries?

Comment: Yup.  It certainly is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  So the solution for me (and hopefully this will help anyone else who's experiencing a similar problem) was to:

1. build CocoaFob as release (I'd already done this, but in the interests of completeness) copy the resultant built framework to /Library/Frameworks and use it from there.
2. Do not attempt to use it in the location where it was built! Neither should you create a symlink in /Library/Frameworks to the location where it was built.

This done, all works well. Phew!